# How to use typed variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use typed variables in javascript? Like integer, string, float...

Comment: What do you mean is there any way to use them? JavaScript is loosely typed so what do you need to do, force the type?

Comment: why you voted down my question?

Comment: @j08691 sorry, but I'm beginner

Comment: one *could* force the type of a property by defining a setter which does a type conversion an assignment; however, that's rather artificial and not really Javascript-y...

Comment: Can't believe nobody mentioned [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays)...

Comment: @GGG: afaik typed arrays are not available in IE and have issues in Opera; the official status with ECMA is [strawman proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:typed_arrays)...

Comment: @Christoph did the OP ever mention the host environment that his code will be running in? Maybe it's for node.js, a browser extension, etc.?

Comment: @GGG: the OP *didn't* mention any host environment - therefore, I found it worthwhile to point out portability issues - I never meant to imply that your answer was incorrect...

Comment: You should read a JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JavaScript variables are not typed.

JavaScript values are, though. The same variable can change (be assigned a new value), for example, from uninitialized to number to boolean to string (not that you'd want to do this!):

```
var x;       // undefined
x = 0;       // number
x = true;    // boolean
x = "hello"; // string
```

Comment: `0` is not `int` but `number`, though - JS has no user-facing integer type (although it has integer operations and specifies internal conversions to integer)...

Comment: @Christoph Thanks. I learned something... and updated the answer.

Comment: `x = '0'` is a string too fyi

Answer (score 9):

**Javascript is dynamically typed**, whereas other languages, C# and Java for example, are statically typed. This means that in Javascript variables can be reassigned to values of any type, and thus that you don't ever need to explicitly denote the type of variables or the return type of functions. If you saw code like this in a statically typed language

```
int x = 5;
x = "hello";
```

you would rightfully expect the compiler to start throwing up a big nasty `TypeError`. Javascript, on the other hand, will happily run this code even though the type changed.

```
var x = 5;
x = "hello";
```

Because variables can change types, the compiler can't know as much information about them. You should expect the tools for Javascript to be inferior to those of Java/C# as far as useful niceties like code completion go. Fewer mistakes will be caught at compile time and you will have to do more runtime debugging than you are probably used to.

That said, this also allows you to be more free with your variables and you can change types at will, which can often be convenient. You can write code like this if you want:

```
var x;               //typeof x === "undefined"
x = "Hello, world!"; //typeof x === "string"
x = 42;              //typeof x === "number"
x = false;           //typeof x === "boolean"
x = {};              //typeof x === "object"
```

Comment: Variables have *no types* so ... the "type of [the] variable" *can't* be changed ;-) What it means is that *any* value can be assigned to *any* variable (or property).

Comment: @pst Variables have types, they just aren't explicitly declared and they can be reassigned to any other type.

Comment: No. Variables have no type in JavaScript. That is a true statement. The *value that they name* -- that is, the value that they *evaluate* to -- has a type.

Comment: @pst Variables are substitutable with the value they are associated with. Unless you are being excessively pedantic, you wouldn't object to somebody saying "the value of a variable", "the type of a variable", "the lifetime of a variable" and so on.

Comment: No they are not. Variables are *not* values and are *not* first-class citizens. When a variable identifier is used in an expression it *evaluates* to the value it "names" (or was "last assigned"). This is a very important distinction in JavaScript. And yes, I do object to "the type of a variable" as *variables have no type*. Also, the term "the lifetime of a variable" is incorrect. Variables have *scopes* while *objects* (values) have *lifetimes*.

Comment: @pst — +1 Pedants keep the world turning. :-)

Comment: In day to day work it would be pedantic to object if a colleague used a phrase like "the type of variable _x_" - it would likely be obvious what they meant. But in the context of a question like this about how the JS language works it is not pedantic to insist that the correct terms are used. (So I agree with @pst on this one.)

Answer (score 3):

Not possible in Javascript, but if you really need it, you should check TypeScript. It is a superset of Javascript that adds optional static typing. It also has class-based programming.

Comment: +1 the big benefit of the typing being to be able to catch errors on compilation, this can now be achieved using javascript compilers. I would also recommend this project: http://jsx.github.io

Answer (score 1):

One of the main characteristics of Javascript is that it is weak typed language. Why do you need strong types anyways?

Comment: Dynamic/static and Weak/strong typing are orthogonal (not related). Python is dynamic/strong, for instance.

Comment: Well in this way Javascript is then both Dynamic\Weakly typed.

Comment: Indeed, it is ;-) Just nit'ing because it addressed weak/strong typing (a property of values) without addressing dynamic/static typing (generally a property of variables/expressions).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing

javascript is a weak and dynamic type..it's dynamic because the variable type is determine in the runtime, and is loosely type because you can perform this operation for example

```
var letter = "2";
var number = 2;
console.log(letter+number);
```

this in java, c# or any other static and stricted type language will make an error but in javascript you get a "22" as result (it is because javascript is weak typed or loosely typed)

now..you've other languages than keep use typed values, like clojure or dart, where for performance reasons, you can use functions or methods with typed arguments, javascript doesn't let this and only accept dynamic values, like ruby...

I hope this help and you can understand my poor english :D

Answer (score 1):

People writing "why shouldn't use it / you shouldn't use it" are wrong. In the next Java Script 2.x specification there is a plan to add strong typed variables.

Meanwhile you may use very simple solution to emulate strong types:

```
var = Object.create( String );
```

After that autocompleting in a lot of IDE (including IntelliJ IDEA) will work great and you have declared and initialized an object of specified type.

Read more on [my blog](http://floatoverflow.blogspot.com/2014/02/emulation-of-strong-types-in-javascript.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple hack to simulate typed variables in Javascript using typed arrays.

```
var a = new Int8Array(1);
a[0]=5;
a[0]=~a[0]; // -6
var b = new Uint8Array(1);
b[0]=5;
b[0]=~b[0]; // 250
```

The only useful reason I know for ever doing this is when you need to use bitwise operations on an unsigned integer when translating code from a typed language which has to do exactly the same in Javascript. Javascript integers are signed by default and bitwise operations can mess up the sign.

Creating a typed array for just a single variable is generally not good for the performance.

Often...

```
var b=5;
b=(~b)&0xff; // 250
```

will do the trick just fine and only 32-bit unsigned integers need to be typed in Javascript to avoid problems with bitwise operations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Typed_array_views

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Int64Array, why?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a loosely typed language, so no, there aren't types as you are used to in some other languages.

Comment: I would say, a *dynamically* (variables are not typed) and *weekly* (implicit conversions between values) typed language... never heard the term *loosely* used in that context before ;-) Python, on the other hand, is dynamic/strong and ActionScript can be used as static/weak.

Comment: Just for giggles, go type javascript typing into google.  Probably the first 3 or 4 hits will come back talking about loosely typed javascript.

Comment: @pst—perhaps you meant **weakly** typed. Or are they typed each week? :-)

Comment: @RobG Their type changes weekly, naturally ;-) (And here I was so proud on catching my incorrect usage of "week" elsewhere...)

Comment: @pst Douglas Crockford, who knows a bit about JavaScript, says, "JavaScript is loosely typed, so we don't use type names in declarations." http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

Comment: @Daniel He says a lot of things. I only agree with a few. I find the Wikipedia [Type system / Dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing) more authoritative myself (note that "loos" does not appear on that page). You will find this usage of terms (of using "dynamically typed" and not "loosely type") prevalent elsewhere as well.

Comment: @pst Wikipedia also says, "In computer science, weak typing (a.k.a. loose typing) is a property attributed to the type systems of some programming languages." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_typing It is not uncommon to hear the term loose typing. Why don't you like it? Does the metaphor weak describe this kind of typing better than loose?

Comment: @Daniel That article should be killed/merged into Type systems (see the attention boxes at top). Note that the confusion of this alternate term is already showing: "loose typing" == "not strong typing" == "weak typing" (per article definitions). This is different than "dynamic typing". The article does not mention "dynamic typing" at all in context of "loose typing" so it would still be "dynamic/loose" (vs. "dynamic/weak"), which, once again, uses a less common term. (Also, "Loose is to ____ as weak is to strong.", and I have never heard of "tight typing".)

Comment: @Daniel It isn't about "being a metaphor" either. It is about having a set of terms that can be used to establish a baseline [when talking about various type systems]. As an example (not relating to metaphors, but about common terms), when talking about the multiplication operator in math, `x * y` is "x times y" or "x multiplied by y", etc. It is not "x cross y" or "x star y" (although this is might what be said when telling someone how to type it on a computer keyboard over a telephone).

Comment: @pst Thanks for you comments. I agree that it is helpful to have a set of terms for describing languages.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS_Byte</title>
        <script>
        class Byte 
        {
            constructor(Value) 
            {
                this.Number = new Uint8Array(1);
                this.Number[0] = Value;
            }
            get Get() 
            {
                return this.Number[0];
            }
            set Set(newValue) 
            {
                this.Number[0] = newValue;
            }
        };
        //On load
        function Load_Page()
        {
            let Byte_Num = new Byte(12);
            document.write(Byte_Num.Get.toString() + "<br>");// -> 12
            Byte_Num.Set = 14;
            document.write(Byte_Num.Get.toString() + "<br>");// -> 14
            Byte_Num.Set = 256;
            document.write(Byte_Num.Get.toString() + "<br>");// -> 0
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Load_Page()"> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible create other variables: Int8, Uint8, Int16, Uint16, Int32, Uint32, Float32, Float64

Answer (score 0):

you can use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) for definition types for values

Comment: TypeScript is different... question was about using typed variables in javascript

Comment: yes of course but i know that, i think it is maybe help

Answer (score 0):

While JavaScript is not explicitly a typed language, it's like a typeless filling in a language sandwich with stronger-typed representations above (in the IDE) and below (in the compiler.) To support IDE-friendly and optimizer-friendly code, there are a number of tricks you can use to obtain explicit types.

JavaScript implementations include just-in-time compilers (JITs) to convert JavaScript into fast machine language. One of the tricks they use is to convert it into an intermediate, strongly typed form. If your goal is performance, you can make life easier by favoring `const` variables and coercing types into more explicit types.

For example, JavaScript supports two number types outside of typed arrays: 64-bit Float (a.k.a. double) and 32-bit integer. While double is the default, you can coerce a number into an integer with `|0`, like this:

```
const myInt = 3.0 | 0;
```

You see this pattern a lot in high-performance code, particularly stuff that was written before typed arrays.

The other reason to have explicit types is to make life easier for developers. Microsoft invented TypeScript so that IDEs (particularly their Visual Studio) can provide code completion, refactoring (in particular renaming), and error detection. It does this by being a strongly typed language. One of the language goals for TypeScript is to provide a future direction for JavaScript. Because of this goal TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and no features are added to TypeScript that couldn't be in a future JavaScript release. Similarly, if future versions of JavaScript break TypeScript, TypeScript will be changed to match JavaScript.

TypeScript isn't JavaScript, so why do I bring it up? Because even if you aren't using it, your editor may be. Since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, the TypeScript compiler can parse JavaScript—and produce type information for all the functions and variables. So if you use Visual Studio, WebStorm, or an editor with a TypeScript plugin, you get type information even with pure JavaScript! (The smarter ones will warn you if you use TypeScript features in JavaScript.)

In fact, one of the arguments against using TypeScript I've heard recently is that JavaScript editors have gotten so good (thanks to the embedded TypeScript compiler) that the advantages no longer outweigh the burden of having another language.

However, to have strong typing (from the IDE's perspective) it helps to make it easy for the compiler to guess how your source files connect together, favor `const`s, and avoid writing functions that return more than one type.