# creating model in angular, check type of data

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm creating a model in angular, any element has its own type:

```
export class myModule {
 constructor(
   public name: string,
   public condition: boolean,
   public age: number){}
}
```

the problem is the type of data is not checked, I can create:

```
mymodule: myModule = new myModule(3,'hi!', true)
```

and it works, in name I have 3, in condition, 'hi!' and in age true.

I guess it should be a way to control it, not checking any data individually, isn't?

Comment: you should get a type error

Comment: can you tell us how you compile it and give us the output of the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your properties outside the constructor. The constructors purpose is to initialize the properties with values. 
Example:

```
export class myModle {
    public name: string,
    public condition: boolean,
    public age: number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you define `myModle` and then use the type below `myModule`?

Comment: sorry, spelling mistake in my post. Updated

Answer (score -2):

I think your answer lies with some further knowledge of JavaScript typing, rather than Angular.  Have a look at this:  [How to use typed variables in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659753/how-to-use-typed-variables-in-javascript)